# Why is android giving an error app is crashing frequently when I haven't experienced any crashes?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I recently deployed my react native app and android is giving me the error "Keep your phone running smoothly. App is crashing frequently. Put it in deep sleep to keep your phone running smoothly". Because of this error my app has stopped showing all fcm notifications and this error only shows up when I am trying to send notifications to the app. Is there any way to debug this error? I have not been experiencing any significant crashes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: test your app in debug mode... try send that notification in debug mode you will the error in console... if its an issue ...
Otherwise there are many terms that make your app lack or make it stuck

Comment: can you give screenshot?